# How to multiply a numpy array by a scalar

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scalar

I have a numpy array and I'm trying to multiply it by a scalar but it keeps throwing an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'
```

My code is:

```
Flux140 = ['0.958900', 'null', '0.534400']
n = Flux140*3
```

Comment: `Flux140` looks more like a  list of string than a numpy array. Elements are strings and, for proper python syntax, they are missing the coma between elements.

Comment: It's definitely not a list of strings. If it was a list of strings, `*` would've been list repetition. That looks like the `print`ed representation of a NumPy object array.

Comment: Are you sure you are using a numpy array? It looks like your submitting a list, and instead it should be a numpy array. you can use the `type` argument to determine if its truly a numpy array

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that your array's `dtype` is a string, and numpy doesn't know how you want to multiply a string by an integer.  If it were a list, you'd be repeating the list three times, but an array instead gives you an error.

Try converting your array's `dtype` from string to float using the `astype` method.  In your case, you'll have trouble with your `'null'` values, so you must first convert `'null'` to something else:

```
Flux140[Flux140 == 'null'] = '-1'
```

Then you can make the type float:

```
Flux140 = Flux140.astype(float)
```

If you want your `'null'` to be something else, you can change that first:

```
Flux140[Flux140 == -1] = np.nan
```

Now you can multiply:

```
tripled = Flux140 * 3
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an array of strings. You want an array of numbers. Parse the input with `float` or something before making the array. (What to do about those `'null'`s depends on your application.)